# Navegar archivos y/o carpetas en Node.js y/o Javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo una duda... se que para navegar mis archivos y/o carpetas en nodejs y/o Javascript es mediante "../" o "./"

Ahora estoy en el archivo "index.js" dentro de la carpeta "productControllers" de acuerdo a mi estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy tratando de requerir un modelo en el archivo "product.js" que esta en la carpera "Models" mediante la siguiente linea de código:

```js
const Product = require('../Models/product');
```

pero me sale un mensaje en consola diciendo que no se puede encontrar ese fichero "product" de la carpeta "Models"

Si alguien podría ayudarme y/o explicarme sobre este tema por favor, les agradecería de antemano...

Comment: `../` es para señalar una capeta anterior y se puede replicar la veces que sea digamos tienes múltiples subdirectorios y tu archivo index esta en este otro directorio con subdirectorios asi `app/nodejs/index.js` y quieres acceder a otro archivo `js` desde ahí, pero esta 2 carpetas o directorios atrás. Entonces accederías a el así `const productos = requiere('../../Models/products.js')`

Comment: Y `./` o `/` es para señalar el directorio actual, aunque en node es mas recomendable usar `./` para señalar el directorio actual, por que llegar a tener conflicto usando `/`

Comment: En tu caso seria `const product = require('./Models/product')`

Comment: Si hice './Models/product' pero me sale que no encuentra ese fichero

Comment: Desde que archivo estas tratando de acceder a el?

Comment: Desde index.js que está en la carpeta productControllers

Comment: Entonces usa `../../Models/product`